# How to load Google Play page with WebView?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, webview, google-play

I use Ionic 3. This code works with other sites but with the url of Google Play it doesn't work. How to load Google Play page with WebView?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

declare var navigator: any;
declare var Connection: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    Connection: any;
    isLaunch: Boolean = false;

    constructor( private platform: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.launch();
        });

    }

    launch() {
        this.isLaunch = true;
        const browser = this.iab.create('https://play.google.com','_self' , "location=yes");

        browser.show();
    }
    }
```

```html
 <ion-content>
    <iframe width='100%' height='100%'
    src="https://play.google.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
   </iframe>
  </ion-content>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to load an app install page? or the main site?

Comment: also you seem to be trying iframe and inAppBrowser at the same time...

Comment: I want to display a music album page, for example: [link] (https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Ariana_Grande_My_Everything?id=Bm633v4dktsed2jsp76mk57qhli&hl=fr)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this.

You are trying to load Google Play in a frame from a different domain name. If Google allowed this, it would be a big security risk, for example, it might let you trick the user into clicking on your site when they thought they were clicking on Play.

In order to prevent this, Google, and other sites use the "[X-FRAME-OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)" header set to "SAMEORIGIN". This tells the browser to not allow this to be put in an iframe unless the source URL also comes from `play.google.com`. Lots of other web pages do this too. You can see this if you open `play.google.com` in chrome, and use the developer tools to look at the header on the request.

Comment: I see. But what i can do for this problem ? I dont want to share the entire site but only a page where there is an album of music.

Comment: You can't. Your only option is to redirect to it in a browser.

Comment: I understand what you want. It isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I used `in-app-browser` module to load my webpage in apps. 
Following code i write to show webpage in apps.

```
  import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
  import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

  declare var navigator: any;
  declare var Connection: any;

  @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
  })
  export class HomePage {
      Connection: any;
      isLaunch: Boolean = false;

      constructor( private platform: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser) {
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
              this.launch();
          });

      }

      launch() {
          this.isLaunch = true;
          const browser = this.iab.create('https://play.google.com','_self' , "location=yes");

          browser.show();
      }
  }
```

```html
<ion-content>

  <div #frame style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important"> 
    <iframe [src]="https://play.google.com" class="iframe" scrolling="yes" ></iframe> </div>
  
</ion-content>
```

Comment: It's good, but my navigation bars are gone, I want google play only on one page friend, what i should do for that please ? 
I would like the page of an album only like this page for example : [link] (https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Ariana_Grande_My_Everything?id=Bm633v4dktsed2jsp76mk57qhli&hl=fr)

Comment: Then appbrowser is not use full for you because it will hide navigation bar and footer of your apps. But you can do this 
`<ion-content>
  <div #frame style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important">
    <iframe [src]="adURL" class="iframe" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
  </div>
</ion-content>
`

Comment: I add this on my .html page, but no change.  Still no navigation bars ... I don't understand.. what i should do? :s